# Antergos installer says I have no /boot partition

Tags: system-installation, uefi, bootable

When attempting to install Antergos(Arch-based Linux distro) I am told that it cannot install as I have not specified a /boot partition, when I appear to have done just that. I have attached a picture of the problem (sorry for the terrible quality.)

[image: Picture of described problem.]

Comment: I dont know the Antergos installer but it says "EFI(/boot)" and your /boot partition is set as ext4 so it can't be used as EFI partition (must be FAT32). It is also more common to mount the EFI partition at /boot/efi than directly at /boot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure to format your `/boot` partition to **FAT32**. It'll work flawlessly :)